# Generate EPSG:4326 Vector Tiles

Tags: tiles, epsg, vector-tiles, mercator

My goal is to create EPSG:4326 vector tiles (using Plate Caree) that can be served in Leaflet. I currently have a .shp file, which I converted to a geojson file using [ogr2ogr](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html). The main obstacle to begin with his seems to be how to create vector tiles from a shape file (or geojson).

[Tippecanoe](https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe) only produces Web Mercator tiles and the [.mbtiles spec](https://github.com/mapbox/mbtiles-spec) says reads:

> "Only the Spherical Mercator projection is supported for presentation (tile display)".

Therefore, I assume the preferred output is a [MVT file](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/mvt.html).

The trouble is, I can't find any tool out there that can produce vector tiles in EPSG:4326. Does anybody know of a good way to produce a `.mvt` file (or a similar output format) in 4326 from a shape file?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the GDAL MVT Driver to create a directory of 4326 vector tiles using the `-dco TILING_SCHEME="EPSG:4326,-180,180,360"` with the `-dco FORMAT=DIRECTORY` flags. https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/mvt.html#dataset-creation-options

Or spin up GeoServer with the vector-tiles plugin to enable geowebcache to cache layers in 4326 vector tiles, also in a directory cache structure. https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/vectortiles/index.html